# Jquery - How do I start a function when div content is changed

Tags: jquery

I searched for a solution like:

```
if( content from $('#div') is change -> start function test(); )
```

I change the content with `$('#div').html('blub');`

Thanks in advance! 
Peter

PS: I know, it is possible with setTimeout, but this is a really dirty solution :/

Comment: Can you not trigger it when you're doing the `.html()` call?

Comment: Can u write a little a example?

Comment: @Peter - For an example, my answer triggers it when I do the `.html()` call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just chain .test() on after .html.

```
$('#div').html('blub').test();
```

To achieve this, simply make a little plugin.

[**Like this (jsFiddle example)**](http://jsfiddle.net/YQHm9/):

```
jQuery.fn.test = function() { 
    // Your test function goes here. 
    return this.each()};
```

That return is needed, since a method must return the jQuery object, unless explicity noted otherwise for a jQuery plugin. Read about jQuery plugins [**here**](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring).

Answer (score 2):

I think the best way to achieve that is to write a custom html function, something like this:

```
function changeHtml(content) {
    this.html(content);
    yourChangeHandler(this);
}
```

Edit: Or with a change event... http://forum.jquery.com/topic/what-is-the-best-way-to-handle-onchange-event-on-a-div

Comment: `$(this)` or `this` not `$this`

Answer (score 0):

It can be done 2 ways
1) create new jquery method and call your test function before calling jquery hml function. So instead of $('#div').html('blub') you will write **$.myhtml($("#div").html())**. **Code below might give you some idea(Got it working)**

```
**jQuery.extend(jQuery, { myhtml: function (arg1, html) { 
         test();
       return arg1.html(html); 
} });** 
 call by $.myhtml($("#div"), $("#div").html()) or $.myhtml($("#div"))
```

2) override jquery html function http://www.bennadel.com/blog/1624-Ask-Ben-Overriding-Core-jQuery-Methods.htm

```
var refhtml = $.fn.html;

$.fn.html = function() {
    $(this).each(function() {
       test();
        refhtml .apply(this, arguments);
    });
};
```

Comment: Nice! I really like your #2 solution. I've never heard about jQuery function overriding before :)

Comment: see this http://www.bennadel.com/blog/1624-Ask-Ben-Overriding-Core-jQuery-Methods.htm . it requires a bit of testing though but it is feasible solution in such scenarios

Answer (score -1):

Just out of curiosity, if you are changing the div content with your code, couldn't you just call `test()` when you change the div?

```
$().event(function(){
    $('#div').html('blub');
    test();  //call your test function
});
```

Answer (score -1):

This will do the job
   `$('#div').change(function(){
         test();
    });`